# querying using Q objects and also using Q single object

Tags: django, django-q

i have 2 queries which i have to join using '|' and apply the final one to get 
the result.First i have list of countries i.e eu countries.and second i have a country from which the user is logged in.I want to join both ones and get the result using Q.First one is `q= Q(country=auth.country)`and second one is
 `q2 = Q(country = settings.euCountries)`, in which settings.enCountries is a django list.Any help in this matter is highly appreciated

Comment: to use JOIN this two models settings and auth must have relationship. is there relationship exists ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need an `OR` for all countries

```
q = [Q(country=auth.country)] + [Q(country=i) for i in settings.euContries]
```

Then

```
import operator
Model.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q))
```

Comment: gonna try this.seems close to answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need multiple `Q()` objects here. You can use the [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup.

```
Q(country_in=[auth.country] + settings.euCountries)
```

Depending on your code, you might not need the `Q` object at all if you can do something like the following:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(country_in=[auth.country] + settings.euCountries)
```